# Implement bottom drawer in android Java

Tags: java, android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I am unable to implement a bottom drawer in android (java) and can not find any working example/tutorial on its usage. Can you write sample code for using a bottom drawer? (https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/#bottom-drawer)

Alternatively, I tried using a drop down menu but my app needs a bottom drawer only

````
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navbottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav">    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>```
````

Here's the code to my bottom navigation view

This is how it should look like[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa0eh.png)

Comment: Actually there are a lot of videos on youtube and articles in popular resources.

Comment: Can you post one? I have looked at a lot of videos and could not find one which uses and explains about bottom drawers in android. Sorry, I have recently started programming in android.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what actually you're looking for? (how it should look)

Comment: You can use a [Bottom Sheet](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md)

Comment: @BlindKai just added a screen shot

Comment: @ParthGargava did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @BlindKai I did, thanks to your help! Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot that you added, I saw something that looks like BottomSheet. To get this look of dialog you probably want to use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` so below I will explain how to implement it inside your Activity.

1) First of all, you need to create a class that will extend from `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and inflate the layout that will be used by this fragment.

```
public class ExampleBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(*R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout*, container, false);
    }
}
```

2) Then you need to create the `*R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout*` layout file that will hold needed views and provide logic for them if it's needed.

3) After that, you can programmatically set Dialog logic. So for example, you could open this dialog by pressing the button.

```
Button buttonDialogBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.btn_sh_dialog);
buttonDialogBottomSheet.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
    ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
    bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "simple tag");
});
```

If you're looking for standard Bottom Sheet just let me know, I will update the answer.
Result of code written above:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuEtG.png)